# Give access to RDS database

Tags: jenkins, rds

i have several databases running in RDS Service.
I'd like to know the best pratice to grant access to developers to these DB.

I tought a solution using jenkins but i dont think this is the best option.

I am trying to avoid give some password to developers.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: You can create them a new, limited privileges user in the RDS for their use. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-users.html

Comment: Do your developers need to run the common: inserts, updates, deletes and selects? Do your developers need dba role? Or Do your developers need to perform some aws actions at RDS instance ?

Comment: They only need  to run the common queries .

Answer (score 0):

As @ceejayoz mentioned you can create a few users with restricted privileges, for example an user who only can run selects on few schemas, another user who can update registers in a few tables.

Answer (score 0):

I can share what we do and what I've seen.  We do A and use B where it is easy.

**A) Standard Users**
For all databases, we have 3 standard users with the following suffixes (_dba, _rw, _ro).  Those all have their own passwords using a strong password generator.
**_dba** is used to deploy scheme and has all rights
**_rw** is used by the application (CRUD on all tables, but can't modify scheme)
**_ro** only has R on all tables and generally given to developers

**Note**: Developers have access to a bastion used for port forwarding and proxycap.  They can query the RDS endpoints from their own machines (DB Tools) going through socks proxy and bastion.

This is lazy method - since creation of users is done programmatically and we feel comfortable giving some developers read only access.  They could write a bad query and slow down system, but they could do that with a specific user so not much different and the bastion logs tell me who really was in if I had to investigate.

**B) UI**
Simple web app with login (ideally MFA) - that provides a way to run queries.  If only for reporting, ideally against R/O copy of system.  Stackoverflow offers one themselves (https://data.stackexchange.com/).

What would be nice is if RDS offered this themselves (linked to your IAM roles).  They offer this on RDS Serverless (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/query-editor.html) and it may be a feature in other RDS versions.  That allows fine control or even lazy control (IAM groups).